# Qt program crashes on quit

Tags: qt

I'm creating one of my first Qt programs. I've got in this a login form, then the provided username and password goes to be checked to MYSQL database.
If there is a record with this username and password, then it is making some

```
ui->something->hide();
```

There are no special Qt console outputs while running, but when I close it by "x" button the program crashes.

I ran it in a debug mode.
What I got:

> "The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating
>   system. 
>   Signal name: SIGSEGV Signal meaning: Segmentation fault

Comment: try to examine the stackframe e.g. with gdb

Comment: Can you post some code here?

Comment: If one can't tell what's the problem just by looking at this assembly, one should throw away computer and give up on programming :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably what is happening is that you have an object that is going out of scope.

When something is deleted, or no longer accessible, and then you try to access it you will get this.

Two actions you should take:

If you create an object in Qt, put it on the heap and then parent it in the Object Tree.

For example:

```
QLabel * label = new QLabel();  // put it on the heap using new

ui->centralWidget()->layout()->addWidget(label);
```

Your label is now in the object tree.  The parent of the label is the Layout object.  Its parent is the central widget.  Its parent is the ui.

When the Window is closed, it will automatically clean up all the children, or in other words, you don't have to call delete on each one.

Occasionally examples show things not on the heap, but that usually doesn't work well in larger examples unless it is a short lived item like a dialog box that isn't referenced anywhere else.

Also in your closeEvent() you should clean up access to your db.  Look at the database examples and find the lines of code used to close the handle(s) to the database.

If you are cleaning up and there is a possibility of it not being available at runtime, you should check.

```
if(label)
    label->setText("I am closing now");
```

And in some cases you may want to set your pointer to zero after it has been deleted or closed.

Hope that helps.